# Soundcloud oEmbed only works with http, not https; all urls are https

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, soundcloud, discourse

**UPDATE**

This issue was fixed by Discourse team and is no longer an issue. no need to read, enjoy hanging with friends or family.

---

I'm working with some soundcloud files that I want to oEmbed in a discourse message board. The urls are https but when you hit the soundcloud enpoint with a https, it causes a 500. For example, the url https://soundcloud.com/smitty1138/the-ink-spots-maybe

See more info here: http://meta.discourse.org/t/curious-about-onebox-and-soundcloud-support/5365

**edit 1**

so you can see an example here:
http://foodiespot.com/t/category-definition-for-favorite-restaurants/4

and:

[image]

Discourse is using onebox which is sending out https requests as you can see in chrome. There might be an issue with how they sound out https requests.

It very well could be an issue with how urls are encoded.

Comment: Hey, could you give me an example of a broken API request? The URL you gave seems to work fine with and without https. I've also tried to do oembed calls and couldn't get 5xx error http://soundcloud.com/oembed.json?url=http://soundcloud.com/smitty1138/the-ink-spots-maybe

Comment: thx for posting, I see what you mean; I've updated the question with some more detail on where we are seeing this happening. It could very well be an issue with onebox but the url seems legit.

Comment: huh, what's onebox? can give me a link to onebox website / docs etc.? **EDIT**: nevermind, I found it http://meta.discourse.org/t/what-is-a-onebox/4546/3

Comment: great - not expecting you to figure this out but would be great for project! On vacation now but will be chekcing in; thx so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was fixed by Discourse team and is no longer an issue